# UNMET PEER Dependency of sinon while installing express.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install, sinon

Getting dependency warning at the time of installing following modules

```
 express.js 
 ejs 
 body-parse
```

and the warning is shown in below image :

[image: warning while installing ejs]

I tried to hunt for the solution but could not get the appropriate solution. However I tried to install `npm install - sinon` but still no luck.

Following are the installed module :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sinon-as-promised` was deprecated with the release of Sinon v2 (because the functionality it provides was added to Sinon directly).

If your own project depends on `sinon-as-promised`, you can remove it as a dependency (and rewrite your tests to use Sinon directly).

If it's a dependency of a dependency, you are most likely not going to be running its tests, so you can ignore the warning.